# reactJS application version counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

I wan't to have a dynamic version counter in my reactJS application.

What are best practises to achieve this?

Each time when merging to master?

Thanks in advance for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a version number in your `package.json`. You can increment it with the command

`npm version [<newversion> | major | minor | patch | premajor | preminor | prepatch | prerelease | from-git]`

Documentation is here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version

You can invoke this manually, or have it as part of a build/deploy script. I do the latter, because the script checks that you are on the develop branch before allowing a deployment to staging, and checks for the master branch before allowing a deployment to production. I can share the script with you if you like.

**UPDATE**

I have put my script on github for you here: https://github.com/mikkelking/deploy-script

My dev environment is using meteor, but only the last step is meteor specific. I used the same script on a sails project before. You will need to make some adjustments to it for your own environment. Have fun!

Comment: that sounds amazing. Can I print the version in the gui

Comment: is it best practise to it like this: `const pckg = require('../../../../../package');
` and then access it?

Comment: The package.json file is not usually accessible to your code, as it is outside your web files. I do some templating at build/release time to generate a small file which includes the version number, so that I can import it and display it somewhere in the GUI.

Comment: can you maybe give me an exmaple how that could look like?

Comment: I'll share my code on github - I will do it tonight, as I have a busy day today

Comment: No hurry. Thanks that would be amazing!

Comment: Updated the answer with the link